# How to format variables to filter through elements on R

Tags: r, list, element

```
v <- files[1:4]
y <- fname[1:4]
date_range <- substr(y[1], 7, 23)
```

How do I make it so that v and y have it so that files[1:4] then becomes file[5:8] and then files[9:13] and so on. I assume it's a for loop, but I'm not sure how to format it. In addition, how do I make it so that date_range uses the first element that v and y use (aka for the first it would be 1 and then 5 and then 9, and so on).

### Data

```r
# files[1:10]
files <- c("1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif", 
"1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS",
"1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif-FailToProcess-Plot.png",
"1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif.png",
"1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif",                  
"1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS",
"1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif-FailToProcess-Plot.png",
"1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif.png",
"1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif",                       
"1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS")

# fname[1:10]
fname <- c("TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif",                       
"TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS",
"TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif-FailToProcess-Plot.png",
"TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif.png",                   
"TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif",                       
"TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS",
"TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif-FailToProcess-Plot.png",
"TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif.png",                   
"TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif",                       
"TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS")
```

Both of these variables include over 100000 elements so I included just the first 10 of each, but they're both essentially just a VERY long list.

---

EDIT:

```
i <- 1 
while (i <= length(files)) {
  start <- i 
  end <- start + 3
  
  v <- files[start:end]
  y <- fname[start:end]
  date_range <- substr(y[1], 7, 23)
  html_block <- make_div(v, date_range)
  
  i <- i + 4
}
```

Comment: And, well: Please make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). `files` and `fname` aren't provided in your question. And please give a small example of your expected output. Unfortunately, I don't understand your second issue.

Comment: rep just repeats it though. I don't want it to repeat the values, I want them to cycle through every 4th element n amount of times (so 1-4 first then 5-8 and so on). rep just repeats elements 1-4 n amount of times.

Comment: files and fname contain 100000+ different elements in them so I don't want to include it. date_range itself just goes to a particular section of fname and takes the date from it (as the date is included in there).

Comment: Please make a small reproducible example. You can use some sample data or extract some of your actual data using `dput(head(YOURDATA))`. Based on your comments I still have no clue what you are trying to achieve and how your expected output should look like.

Comment: Do you want me to share my code on codeshare.io ? There's only like 100 lines of code so it's not a whole lot since I'm not overly sure how to make it reproducible since a lot of my code is just me making a function.

Comment: Please, have a careful look at this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/8237186. The idea is to provide a minimum (small) reproducible (so we can recreate in our computers) example. The best you prepare your question, the easier it will be for people to help you and the more likely you will get a helpful answer and we avoid spending too much time asking one another what exactly you mean, how your data looks like, and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, maybe this is what you are looking for??

#### edit:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  start <- i * 4 - 4 + 1
  end <- start + 3
  
  v <- files[start:end]
  y <- fname[start:end]
  date_range <- substr(y[1], 7, 23)
  
  
  cat("\nstart:", start, "\t| end:", end, "\t| date_range", date_range)
}

# start: 1  | end: 4    | date_range 18580907-18580908
# start: 5  | end: 8    | date_range 18580908-18580909
# start: 9  | end: 12   | date_range 18580910-18580911
```

#### edit 2:

A somewhat more flexible and explicit approach to update the counter and takes into account length of vector `files`

```r
i <- 1 
while (i <= length(files)) {
  start <- i 
  end <- start + 3
  
  v <- files[start:end]
  y <- fname[start:end]
  date_range <- substr(y[1], 7, 23)
  
  
  cat("\nstart:", start, "\t| end:", end, "\t| date_range", date_range)
  i <- i + 4
}
```

Comment: date_range is returning back NA and I'm not too sure why. But yes, this is on the right track!

Comment: can you provide a sample of files and fname? (please, have a look on the links sent as comments to your question.)

Comment: I added them to your answer!

Comment: @NathanDrake Please don't edit the answer. You can easily put your data into your question. I moved your suggested edit to your question.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Did seeing those variables help you with understanding?

Comment: it does help immensely. What do you expect to get with `substr(y[1], 7, 23)` ? Does my edit solve it? If not, please provide the desired output. If it does solve, please consider ticking the check mark :)

Comment: Hi sorry, just saw this now. So your edit has it perfectly set up for ONE thing, not for everything. I have to change the number in 1:3 to 1:4 for example to get a different output. What I am trying to accomplish is making an output for each and every individual differently named file (not different file extensions; those are grouped together).

Comment: I will happily click the check mark once it is done! :)

Comment: the loop only goes over the first few files.  You said you had more than 100.000 elements, so a longer loop would be indeed necessary (but also longer than 1:4). See if my second edit helps in solving your question, by making the counter a bit more explicit...

Comment: I have a function I use with this for loop that takes v and date_range and makes a div with every loop created here. Should I do something like what I put in the edit?

Comment: I would suggest you break your problems into smaller chunks and tackle one at a time instead of editing and updating this question over and over. You can open a new question, refer to this one and state what you want to achieve and what you tried and how and why it didn't work. This questions was originally about the for loop logic, which is already solved, so now you can start anew and focus on the new problem at hand.