# Is there an R function that allows me to group a list together based off identical characters

Tags: r, list, loops, while-loop, character

```
i <- 1 
while (i <= length(files)) {
  start <- i 
  end <- start + 3
  
  v <- files[start:end]
  y <- fname[start:end]
  date_range <- substr(y[1], 7, 23)
  html_block <- make_div(v, date_range)
  
  top <- readLines("header.html")
  bottom <- readLines("footer.html")
  
  
  # This will write just the div block
  write(x = html_block, file = paste0(date_range, "-block.html"))
  
  # This will write a working website
  write(x = c(top, "<body>", html_block, "</body>", bottom), 
        file = paste0(date_range, "-website.html"))
  
  i <- i + 4
}
```

So, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68338112/how-to-format-variables-to-filter-through-elements-on-r) will provide a reference on how I've gotten here. And the above code is in fact doing exactly what I want it to. The goal was for it to loop through the lengthy list of files that I have and then make a div for each file whose only difference is file type (i.e. everything else in the file name was the same). However, that is not what this is doing as this just takes every 4 files and puts them together. The issue with this is that not every 4 files are of the same file (some are just 2 or 3 for example; see fname below for example). So what I was wondering is whether there is a way to cycle through each file name and see whether if the characters from x to y are the same, and if so, those can then be grouped together and then so on.

```
# fname[1:10]
fname <- c("TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif",                       
"TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS",
"TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif-FailToProcess-Plot.png",
"TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif.png",                   
"TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif",                       
"TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS",
"TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif-FailToProcess-Plot.png",
"TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif.png",                   
"TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif",                       
"TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS")
```

The first 10 elements of fname (a variable that contains all of the file names which is significantly more than 10) is displayed above. Is there a way for me to check if the 7th to the 24th element (i.e. 18580907-18580908 which is the date) matches the following one and, if so, can those be grouped together and then continue that cycle for every single file that follows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an alternative solution more similar to what you already have would be creating a vector of unique data-ranges, and then extracting the group of files for each data range and then carrying on with the tasks in your loops:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
fname <- c("TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif",                       
           "TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS",
           "TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif-FailToProcess-Plot.png",
           "TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif.png",                   
           "TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif",                       
           "TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS",
           "TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif-FailToProcess-Plot.png",
           "TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif.png",                   
           "TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif",                       
           "TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS")

# create a vector of unique date ranges
(date_range_unique_vec <- str_sub(fname, start = 7, end = 23) %>% 
    unique())

for (each_date_range in date_range_unique_vec) {
  
  # extract group of file names for each unique date range
  group_fnames <- fname[str_detect(fname, each_date_range)]
  
  { # from here!!
    html_block <- make_div(group_fnames, each_date_range)
    top <- readLines("header.html")
    bottom <- readLines("footer.html")
    
    # This will write just the div block
    write(x = html_block, file = paste0(each_date_range, "-block.html"))
    
    # This will write a working website
    write(x = c(top, "<body>", html_block, "</body>", bottom),
          file = paste0(each_date_range, "-website.html"))
    
  }# to here, I cannot run locally.  
  

  # 
  cat(each_date_range, "\n")
  cat(group_fnames, "\n")
  cat("\n")
}
```

**Note:** I cannot check the optional `{ }` block in the middle of the loop in my computer. While I think it should be fine, maybe you might have to adapt it a little.

Comment: Some mild tinkering was needed, but this did in fact end up doing exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have an additional question to add on to this that I've found has risen. What you sent worked really well for me, however, I am having an issue in that there are files that have identical dates that are also showing up. They are in separate sub-directories called "FailedToProcess" and are showing up in those same divs and having those links show up as well. Is it possible to differentiate between the two in that the ones that are under the "FailedToProcess" subdirectory do not show up as well? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. it is possible, You should include only the files that should show up in the `date_range_unique_vec` vector, if I understood you correctly. To be able to say something more concrete I would need more information. You can write a new question and provide your new code (since you said it required some modification) and more details on how your files are stored and I will gladly have a look at it. You can answer to this comment with the link to the new question.

Comment: Here's the [link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68423114/is-there-an-r-function-that-allows-me-to-group-a-list-together-based-off-identic). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the dates using `substr()` and then group them in a list, if that is what you want. You then get a list of dates, each containing a vector of filenames:

```
date = substr(fname,7,23)

directory = list()
for(d in unique(date)){
  directory[[d]]=fname[date==d]
}
```

The output is:

```
> directory
$`18580907-18580908`
[1] "TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif"                       
[2] "TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS"
[3] "TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif-FailToProcess-Plot.png"
[4] "TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif.png"                   

$`18580908-18580909`
[1] "TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif"                       
[2] "TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS"
[3] "TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif-FailToProcess-Plot.png"
[4] "TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif.png"                   

$`18580910-18580911`
[1] "TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif"                       
[2] "TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS"
```

EDIT: I concede that the answer by r2evans is way better. I was oblivious of the `split()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Two thoughts:

1. If you want a `list`, where each element of it is a vector of the related filenames, then

   ```r
   groupedlist <- split(fname, substr(fname, 7, 23))
   groupedlist
   # $`18580907-18580908`
   # [1] "TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif"                        "TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS"
   # [3] "TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif-FailToProcess-Plot.png" "TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif.png"                   
   # $`18580908-18580909`
   # [1] "TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif"                        "TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS"
   # [3] "TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif-FailToProcess-Plot.png" "TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif.png"                   
   # $`18580910-18580911`
   # [1] "TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif"                        "TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS"
   ```
2. If you want a vector (perhaps to add to a `data.frame` identifying which group they belong to, and you don't want to use just `substr(.)` to group on the substrings, then you can get integer representations of those groups with

   ```r
   as.integer(factor(substr(fname, 7, 23)))
   #  [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3
   ```

Comment: How would I be able to then implement this into the while loop such that a div is then created for each date?

Comment: I don't really know what your intended output is for these three groups and the strings they contain. I understand the premise of `<div>...</div>`, but ... are they just raw text in the div? unordered-lists? something else?