# Is there an R function that allows me to group a list together based off identical characters but that will separate them if there is a subdirectory

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, character

My goal was to make a div with all of the individual files that are separated by their respective dates. What I used in that question's answer worked for me, however, I am having an issue in that there are files that have identical dates that are also showing up. They are in separate sub-directories called "FailedToProcess" and are showing up in those same divs and having those links show up as well. Is it possible to differentiate between the two in that the ones that are under the "FailedToProcess" subdirectory do not show up as well, but show up in another separate div? Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
# create a vector of unique date ranges
(date_range_unique_vec <- str_sub(fname, start = 7, end = 23) %>% 
    unique())

for (each_date_range in date_range_unique_vec) {
  
  # extract group of file names for each unique date range
  group_fnames <- files[str_detect(files, each_date_range)]
  
  {
    html_block <- make_div(group_fnames, each_date_range)
    top <- readLines("header.html")
    bottom <- readLines("footer.html")
    
    # This will write just the div block
    write(x = html_block, file = paste0(each_date_range, "-block.html"))
    
    # This will write a working website
    write(x = c(top, "<body>", html_block, "</body>", bottom),
          file = paste0(each_date_range, "-website.html"))
    
  }  
  
  cat(each_date_range, "\n")
  cat(group_fnames, "\n")
  cat("\n")
}
```

EDIT:

```
files <- list.files(recursive = TRUE)

file_name <- strsplit(files, "/")

# extract the file names themselves
fname <- unlist(lapply(file_name, FUN = function(x) { 
  if(length(x) == 2) { x[2] } else { x[3] } }))
```

Comment: Don't overthink it. The "date selection magic" is here: `files[str_detect(files, each_date_range)]`. You can use the same vector-subsetting technique to apply additional filtering.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about it though. Would I use an if statement or what?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be keeping only the relevant paths in the vector `files`. There are multiple ways of doing it. Possibly directly at the creation of the object `files`. Or later (in case you also need to deal with the `FailedToProcess` files elsewhere). 

Can you tell us how you create the `files` and `fnames` objects (with code)? In the previous question we can see how they look like (though all of them are the `FailedToProcess` folder, in which case, a more representative sample of the filenames would be more helpful.

Comment: @NathanDrake yes, that is one possible solution: you could loop through `group_fnames` and use an `if` to select only the desired items. However, I encourage you to read up on [subsetting with `logical` (aka "Boolean") vectors](https://homerhanumat.github.io/r-notes/subsetting-with-logical-vectors.html).

Comment: So for the first several years, all of the files are part of a Failed to Process subdirectory because the technology wasn't there at the time (what I'm assuming), but in the latter years, some failed to process while others did not! That's also why the first few elements in files/fname are Failed to Process (since it's a part of the first few years). So as a result, I DO need all of the files including FailedToProcess. In terms of how I made those variables, I will include it in my initial question, however, it contains nearly 10000 elements so showing it would not be helpful.

Comment: Okay. How do the file names look like? (including when they are not in the `FailToProcess` folder.

Comment: What do you mean by that? The names themselves are the ones that just have the date on them, however, "files" itself has all the directories that the files link to (and if it's part of FailedToProcess, that one is there as well). For example, files[90000] is "1939/AGC-D-19390310-19390312.tif.png" whereas files[1] is "1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One one way of achieving your goal would be as the following.

The main differences from what you had previously are that the are two calls to the html writing functions inside the loop, first for the processed files and then for the unprocessed ones. The `length()>0` condition is just to make sure you only try to write the html files if there are indeed either processed or unprocessed files for each date range.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# representative sample of files
files <- c("1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif", 
                     "1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS",
                     "1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif-FailToProcess-Plot.png",
                     "1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580907-18580908.tif.png",
                     "1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif",                  
                     "1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS",
                     "1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif-FailToProcess-Plot.png",
                     "1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580908-18580909.tif.png",
                     "1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif",                       
                     "1858/FailedToProcess/TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS",
                     "1858/TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif",                       
                     "1858/TOR-D-18580910-18580911.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS",
                     "1939/AGC-D-19390310-19390312.tif", 
                     "1939/AGC-D-19390310-19390312.tif.png",
                     "1939/AGC-D-19390310-19390312.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS",
                     "1940/A06-D-19400306-19400306.tif", 
                     "1940/A06-D-19400306-19400306.tif.png",
                     "1940/A06-D-19400306-19400306.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS",
                     "1941/A02-D-19410302-19410302.tif", 
                     "1941/A02-D-19410302-19410302.tif.png",
                     "1941/A02-D-19410302-19410302.tif-FailToProcess-Data.RDS")

# you can get the file name (without full path) with basename()
fname <- basename(files)

# create a vector of unique date ranges from processed files
(date_ranges_vec <- str_sub(basename(files), start = 7, end = 23) %>% 
        unique())

# since it does not change for all datse, can go outside of loop for speed
top <- readLines("header.html")
bottom <- readLines("footer.html")

for (each_date_range in date_ranges_vec) {
    
    # extract group of file names for each unique date range. Processed first
    group_fnames <- files[str_detect(files, each_date_range) & !str_detect(files, "/FailedToProcess/")]
    
    # check that there is at least one file that respects above conditions
    if (length(group_fnames)>0) {
        cat(each_date_range, ": Writing processed.", "\n")
        html_block <- make_div(group_fnames, each_date_range)
        write(x = html_block, file = paste0(each_date_range, "-block.html"))
        write(x = c(top, "<body>", html_block, "</body>", bottom),
                    file = paste0(each_date_range, "-website.html"))
    }
    
    # extract group of file names for each unique date range. Not procesed
    group_fnames_fail <- files[str_detect(files, each_date_range) & str_detect(files, "/FailedToProcess/")]
    
    # check that there is at least one file that respects above conditions
    if (length(group_fnames_fail)>0) {
        cat(each_date_range, ": Writing not processed.", "\n")
        html_block <- make_div(group_fnames_fail, each_date_range)
        write(x = html_block, file = paste0(each_date_range, "-block.html"))
        write(x = c(top, "<body>", html_block, "</body>", bottom),
                    file = paste0(each_date_range, "-website.html"))
    }
}
```

```
18580907-18580908 : Writing not processed. 
18580908-18580909 : Writing not processed. 
18580910-18580911 : Writing processed. 
18580910-18580911 : Writing not processed. 
19390310-19390312 : Writing processed. 
19400306-19400306 : Writing processed. 
19410302-19410302 : Writing processed.
```

In this setup the `div`s would be sorted by date. If you wanted to have all processed files first and then all unprocessed ones you could do it by running to loops, one over the processed files only and another over the unprocessed ones.

Comment: Would it be possible to take these dates and make a calendar out of it so that if someone were to click on a particular date of the calendar (year, month, day), they would see the files associated with that date?

Comment: That being said, what you wrote worked perfectly, so once again, thank you!

Comment: Or if not a calendar (but that would be ideal), can I make it so that if a user were to input the particular year, month, and day, the corresponding image "block" would show up?

Comment: It is possible, but this would be rather a javascript than a R problem. One possible way would be either writing a shinyapp or creating a DT::datatable() with links to each image. The datatable() has a search field built in. See this example: https://rpubs.com/erblast/369527

Comment: I already have the clickable file links aspect of it created! That's in a previous code (can edit above and post that), but basically I made a function that makes it all into a div that contains clickable links to every file of that particular date. Now, I'm just trying to figure out how to make it so that if a user enters a particular date, they see the results that correspond to it. Does that make sense? I can make a new question if you'd like!

Comment: Like basically, they search up a particular date, and then get the corresponding <div> block (that I've already made for each and every one) pop up and show them the relevant content for that date.

Comment: this would rather be a javascript problem, then. Right?  feel free to write up a new question, but I am afraid I cannot help you with that.